# HighChart data table keeps adding number of tables at bottom on every call

Tags: highcharts

I am using HighChart library to show Pie Chart on my page, I am keeping showTable always true to show every time.

The problem is whenever data binds to charts using JQuery Ajax post dynamically, i see proper data in chart but also it keeps adding new data table everytime at the bottom. E.g. First time there will be only one table, after another call there will be two tables added and so on. Why Hightcharts not updating the same table again or is there a way to kill any existing table.?

```
 hc = Highcharts.chart(chartName, {
                chart: {
                    type: 'pie',
                    options3d: {
                        enabled: false,
                        alpha: 45
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#575962'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: title,
                    style: {
                        color: '#575962',
                        fontweight: '400'
                    }
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Current Month(Top 10)'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        innerSize: 100,
                        depth: 45,
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                exporting: {
                    showTable: true
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Price',
                    data: [],
                    dataLabels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            //const point = this.point;
                            //return '<span style="color: #575962;font-size:11px;font-weight: 400">' +
                            //    point.name + ': $' + point.y + '</span>';
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
```

[image]

Why Hightcharts not updating the same table again or is there a way to kill any existing table.?

Comment: Hi @Jignesh, How do you apply the newly received data? As you can see in this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8ac0joxm/ the data table is correctly updated after each dynamic data update.

Comment: thank you @ppotaczek, Appreciate your help, I posted my reply and answer in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by removing the series on each call and adding them again with new data. Hope this helps if anyone else looking and couldn't find any other answer.

```html
//Removing Series
 while (hc.series.length > 0) {
            hc.series[0].remove(false);
        }

//Adding new Series
        hc.addSeries({
            name: 'Price',
            data: [],
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    const point = this.point;
                    return '<span style="color: #575962;font-size:11px;font-weight: 400">' +
                        point.name + ': $' + point.y + '</span>';
                }
            }
        });

//Binding Series data
            var res = result.Data.slice(0, 10);
            res.forEach(function (element, index) {
                hc.series[0].addPoint({
                    name: element.ResourceGroupName,
                    y: element.TotalMonthlyPrice,
                });
            });
```